# Recovery mode raid1 centos - how to?

Tags: fsck

I'm having a problem with fsck. 
Using cat /proc/mdstat
I have this:

```
md0 : active raid1 sda1[3] sdb1[2]
      524276 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
```

I made a mistake when first using fsck, cos I used fsck /dev/sda1, but I remembered then that I have raid1 on this server - the proper use would have been fsck /dev/md0. I used then fsck /dev/md0 but I keep getting nothing.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Do you expect something else?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i am aware an fsck on a soft raid member wont damage anything as long as you DO NOT say yes to fixing any reported errors

Your output from /proc/mdstat is completely normal and no recovery/rebuild operations are running

If you get no output from fsck /dev/md1 - I would guess this means that everything is fine, are you getting any output at all?

Is the soft raid mounted or unmounted? you normally have to/should unmount the volume before running fsck - especially to repair any errors.